# Javascript Multiple Word Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working with the jQuery datatables library and passing a regular expression to filter a particular column.

I'd like to pass something like "Test 123" and "Test 321" and it return any rows with either of those two words.

I have tried something like this without any luck:

```
/(?=.*?TEST 123)(?=.*?TEST 321).*/i
```

I've also tried this, but only returns the second result

```
TEST 123|TEST 321
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the 'OR' condition to the test -

```
(TEST 123)|(TEST 321)
```

Tested at http://regexpal.com

Comment: You are the man...apparently the parens did it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/(TEST 123)|(TEST 321)/i
```